# How to Delete the cookie for more than one same application?

Tags: asp.net

My Problem is! I Want to open more than one Application in same Browser,But All The Application are Same.& I want Different login page at every tab.

First time i opened that application in new tab & I logged in ,
Second time ,if i open the same Application in another tab Means ,I Want fresh Login page and at the same time my previous Login page will be became logged out..
How can i Do that?
One more thing, i don't need any changes to do Browser settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a session cookie, i.e., a cookie that is only valid during the current session.

You turn a cookie into a session cookie like so:

```
cookie.Expires = DateTime.MinValue;
```

When the user opens another tab in IE or Chrome (don't know about Firefox), the server sees this as a new session because it doesn't receive the session cookies from the other tab.